# Setting CALayer color in raywenderlich.com article

Tags: ios, calayer, uicontrol

I have a question about this article https://www.raywenderlich.com/7595-how-to-make-a-custom-control-tutorial-a-reusable-slider

I **substitute**

```swift
var trackTintColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1) {
    didSet {
      trackLayer.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
  }
```

**with**

```swift
var trackTintColor = UIColor(red: 56, green: 81, blue: 117, alpha: 1) {
    didSet {
      trackLayer.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
  }
```

in **RangeSlider.swift** .

**But the color that I want won't appear and RangeSlider have no background color.**

Could you let me know why? And How could I make RangeSlider have the color that I want?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value range of the `UIColor` components must be between 0.0 and 1.0 which is pretty obvious in the first example.

You could divide the `UInt8` values by 255 (as floating point numbers to get correct floating point results)

```
var trackTintColor = UIColor(red: 56.0/255.0, green: 81.0/255.0, blue: 117.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0) { ...
```

or pre-calculate the values, or define the color in the asset catalog